# Algebraic simplification of the gamma function $\int^1_u\frac{\Gamma(a+b+c)}{\Gamma(a)\Gamma(b)\Gamma(c)}v^{-(b+c)}(1-v)^{b-1}u^{a+b-1}(v-u)^{c-1}dv$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, gamma-function

I'm taking an undergraduate statistics course. I have a problem in which $X\sim BETA(a,b)$ and $Y\sim BETA(a+b,c)$,first I found the joint PDF of $U=XY$ and $V=X$ which is the function I'm integrating. I'm trying to show that $U\sim BETA(a,b+c)$. The solution has a step where the integral to be evaluated transforms from this,

\begin{equation*}
\int^1_u\frac{\Gamma(a+b+c)}{\Gamma(a)\Gamma(b)\Gamma(c)}v^{-(b+c)}(1-v)^{b-1}u^{a+b-1}(v-u)^{c-1}dv
\end{equation*}

to this.
\begin{equation*}
=\frac{\Gamma(a+b+c)}{\Gamma(a)\Gamma(b+c)}u^{a-1}(1-u)^{b+c-1}\int^1_u\frac{\Gamma(b+c)}{\Gamma(b)\Gamma(c)}\frac{v^{-(b+c)}(1-v)^{b-1}u^{b-1}(v-u)^{c-1}}{(1-u)^{b+c-1}}dv
\end{equation*}

The leftover integral should evaluate to $1$. Then the left hand side is the answer sought. I'm having trouble understanding how the function, especially the fraction with individual gamma functions, simplifies or breaks apart. I thought maybe it has to do with the original $X$ and $Y$ distributions. But there is no $(b+c)$ term involved.

Comment: for starters: pull the $v$-indpendent rubbish out of the integral

Comment: I wholeheartedly second @Tired here. Half of the stuff in your integral is irrelevant. Pull it outside the integral.